# Pagination - Twitter's people you follow

Tags: android, json, api, twitter

im developing an Android application for twitter that will sync data coming from the people you follow.

The problem is that:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/friends.json
```

provides me the last 100 persons ive followed and i wanted to display only 20 for each 'page'.

I believe that the 'cursor' parameter doesnt do what i need, so i'm trying to figure out a way to store it.

Can you guys give me enlightenment?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add a parameter count=, and combine this with the cursor parameter.  Try

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/friends.json?count=20&cursor=-1

Comment: wow, i didnt think there was a count parameter! thank you mccv!